# Query data from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin

I am trying to query data from DynamoDB in my android app using kotlin. The code should be correct, but looking at the logs, it doesn't seem to be executing the code since I'm not receiving any type of results from it. Wondering if anyone has any idea what is happening based off the logs?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzZ5D.png)

```
fun getUserData(email: String) {
    println("We will get the userdata!!!!!!!!")
    Amplify.DataStore.query(
        User::class.java,
        { items ->
            while (items.hasNext()) {
                val item = items.next()
                Log.i("Amplify", "Queried item: " + item.name)
            }
        },
        { failure -> Log.e("Tutorial", "Could not query DataStore", failure) }
    )
}
```

> 023-04-21 19:41:19.981 16806-16893 TrafficStats            com.example.aupairconnect            D  tagSocket(119) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.011 16806-16806 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.aupairconnect            D  Compat change id reported: 171228096; UID 10162; state: ENABLED
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.211 16806-16881 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Orchestrator lock released.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.211 16806-16881 MyAmplifyApp            com.example.aupairconnect            I  DataStore started
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.531 16806-16887 e.aupairconnect         com.example.aupairconnect            W  Long monitor contention with owner pool-5-thread-1 (16886) at void com.amplifyframework.api.aws.SubscriptionEndpoint.requestSubscription(com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLRequest, com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AuthorizationType, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Action)(SubscriptionEndpoint.java:196) waiters=0 in void com.amplifyframework.api.aws.SubscriptionEndpoint.requestSubscription(com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLRequest, com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AuthorizationType, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Action) for 562ms
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.666 16806-16888 e.aupairconnect         com.example.aupairconnect            W  Long monitor contention with owner pool-5-thread-1 (16886) at void com.amplifyframework.api.aws.SubscriptionEndpoint.requestSubscription(com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLRequest, com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AuthorizationType, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Action)(SubscriptionEndpoint.java:196) waiters=1 in void com.amplifyframework.api.aws.SubscriptionEndpoint.requestSubscription(com.amplifyframework.api.graphql.GraphQLRequest, com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AuthorizationType, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Consumer, com.amplifyframework.core.Action) for 695ms
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.793 16806-16880 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Started subscription processor for models: [User] of types [ON_CREATE, ON_UPDATE, ON_DELETE].
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.801 16806-16893 TrafficStats            com.example.aupairconnect            D  tagSocket(120) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
> 2023-04-21 19:41:20.975 16806-16860 EGL_emulation           com.example.aupairconnect            D  app_time_stats: avg=73.29ms min=0.58ms max=656.79ms count=17
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.041 16806-16806 OnBackInvokedCallback   com.example.aupairconnect            W  OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
> Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.060 16806-16904 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Successfully sync'd down model state from cloud.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.061 16806-16880 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Starting processing subscription data buffer.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.061 16806-16880 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Started the orchestrator in API sync mode.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.061 16806-16879 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Started processing the mutation outbox. Pending mutations will be published to the cloud.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.068 16806-16806 System.out              com.example.aupairconnect            I  We will get the userdata!!!!!!!!
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.068 16806-16806 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Orchestrator lock acquired.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.068 16806-16885 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  DataStore plugin initialized.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.074 16806-16806 System.out              com.example.aupairconnect            I  We will get the userdata!!!!!!!!
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.321 16806-16885 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Orchestrator lock released.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.321 16806-16806 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Orchestrator lock acquired.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.322 16806-16882 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  DataStore plugin initialized.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:21.575 16806-16882 amplify:aws-datastore   com.example.aupairconnect            I  Orchestrator lock released.
> 2023-04-21 19:41:24.656 16806-16911 ProfileInstaller        com.example.aupairconnect            D  Installing profile for com.example.aupairconnect

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/auf0U.png)

I tried looking through the Amplify's documentation for more clarification on if I'm missing anything, but it looks like it is all there.

Comment: Please do not provide [images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). They can't be searched or compiled. Copy/paste your code and relevant logs/errors as actual text and format as code.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated it. Hopefully it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Kotlin to invoke Amazon DynamoDB (and other AWS Services), then I strongly recommend that you use the **AWS SDK for Kotlin** and the **[DynamoDbClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/kotlin/api/latest/dynamodb/index.html)**. You can read the DEV Guide here:

[AWS SDK for Kotlin Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html)

To query data from an Amazon DynamoDB table using the Kotlin SDK, use this code:

```
package com.kotlin.dynamodb

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.kotlin.query.import]
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.QueryRequest
import kotlin.system.exitProcess
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.kotlin.query.import]

/**
Before running this Kotlin code example, set up your development environment,
including your credentials.
For more information, see the following documentation topic:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html
*/

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val usage = """
    Usage:
        <tableName>
    Where:
        tableName - The Amazon DynamoDB table to scan (for example, Music3).
        partitionKeyName - The partition key name of the Amazon DynamoDB table (for example, Artist).
        partitionKeyVal - The value of the partition key that should match (for example, Famous Band).
    """

    if (args.size != 3) {
        println(usage)
        exitProcess(0)
    }

    val tableName = args[0]
    val partitionKeyName = args[1]
    val partitionKeyVal = args[2]

    // For more information about an alias, see:
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html
    val partitionAlias = "#a"
    val count = queryDynTable(tableName, partitionKeyName, partitionKeyVal, partitionAlias)
    print("There is $count item in $tableName")
}

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.kotlin.query.main]
suspend fun queryDynTable(
    tableNameVal: String,
    partitionKeyName: String,
    partitionKeyVal: String,
    partitionAlias: String
): Int {

    val attrNameAlias = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    attrNameAlias[partitionAlias] = partitionKeyName

    // Set up mapping of the partition name with the value.
    val attrValues = mutableMapOf<String, AttributeValue>()
    attrValues[":$partitionKeyName"] = AttributeValue.S(partitionKeyVal)

    val request = QueryRequest {
        tableName = tableNameVal
        keyConditionExpression = "$partitionAlias = :$partitionKeyName"
        expressionAttributeNames = attrNameAlias
        this.expressionAttributeValues = attrValues
    }

    DynamoDbClient { region = "us-east-1" }.use { ddb ->
        val response = ddb.query(request)
        return response.count
    }
}
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.kotlin.query.main]
```

The Kotlin SDK is great to use within an Android Studio project as well. Here is a tutorial that shows you how:

[Creating a publish/subscription Android application that translates messages using the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/kotlin/usecases/subpub_app_android)

Comment: Seems interesting. I didn't know about the SDK, only the API. Although the SDK is interesting, I'm already working with the API and I have most of the app backend completed already, so switching would mean I'd have to start the app over and redesign the backend. Thank you though!

Comment: Just letting you know about the Kotlin SDK where you get full benefits of the Kotlin programming language such as coroutines, etc. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/coroutines.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that the data wasn't coming through due to the data not being in the AmplifyDataStore Table on DynamoDb, but strangely it was in the User Table. Deleting and then saving the data again in the app, it was able to save to both tables, therefore able to be accessed by the API.